# How to get the Same product Name to be displayed only once in a year

Tags: visualforce

Can any one help me out in this.The Scenario is the product name get repeated in different quarters(Say q1,q2,q3,q4) and need to filter by adding its quantity and Amount.I get the Quantities and Amount with the total displayed but the Product Name gets repaeated for all the 4 quarters.

1)How to get the Same product Name to be displayed only once .

This is Table i get for 4 Quarters .

```
ProductName   Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4    Total 
ABC           100    200   300    400     1000
PQR            50    150   250    350      800
XYZ           200    300   400    500     1400
ABC           100    200   300    400     1000
PQR            50    150   250    350      800
XYZ           200    300   400    500     1400
ABC           100    200   300    400     1000
PQR            50    150   250    350      800
XYZ           200    300   400    500     1400
ABC           100    200   300    400     1000
PQR            50    150   250    350      800
XYZ           200    300   400    500     1400
```

But the Table should be :

```
 ProductName   Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4    Total 
 ABC           100    200   300    400     1000
 PQR            50    150   250    350      800
 XYZ           200    300   400    500     1400
```

Visual Force :

```
<h3>OpportunityForecast Details</h3>
 <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="3"  ></td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="5" >FORECAST DATE</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>              
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Opportunity Name</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">PartNumbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"></td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q1 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q2 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q3 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q4 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">MonthText</td>
                <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading">Grand<br/>Total </td> 
              </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!disp_list}" var="opf">
            <tr>

                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Opportunity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Product}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data" >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter1[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!Amount1[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter2[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!Amount2[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter3[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!Amount3[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!Amount4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Month_Text }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter1[opf.gmod_Product]+Quarter2[opf.gmod_Product]+Quarter3[opf.gmod_Product]+Quarter4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!Amount1[opf.gmod_Product]+Amount2[opf.gmod_Product]+Amount3[opf.gmod_Product]+Amount4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/><br/></td>
            </tr>
           </apex:repeat> 
        </tbody>
       <tfoot>
                   <tr class="foot">
                   <tr>

                     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data">SubTotal :</td>
                     <td colspan="0"  class="header-table-data"  >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/> </td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     </tr>
                         <tr>

                       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left"  align="right" class="header-table-heading">GrandTotal</td>
                       <td colspan="0"  class="header-table-heading"  >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/> </td>
                       <td colspan="1"   class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                       </tr>

                   </tr>

               </tfoot> 
                  </table> 

</apex:page>
```

Code :

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

      public Map<String,Decimal> PartMap{get;set;}

     //   public Map<String,Decimal> PartMapQuantity{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter1{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter2{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter3{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter4{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount1{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount2{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount3{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount4{get;set;}

       public Competitor__c com{get;set;}

       public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist{get;set;}

       public Id qId {get;set;}

       Public string all{get;set;}

//Declare a wrapper class  

       public class Wrapperclass{

 //custom wrapper datatype  

       Public string Name{get;set;}  
       Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
       Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
       Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
       Public string Probability{get;set;}  
       Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
       Public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

       Public string Segment{get;set;}  
       Public string Application{get;set;}  
       Public string Persona{get;set;}  
       Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

       Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

       Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
       Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
       Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
       Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
       Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
       Public string Other_information{get;set;}  

       Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
       Public string Volume{get;set;} 
       Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

       Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
       Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
       Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
       Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}




       Public wrapperClass(){} 

  }

       Public QuoteContentController(){}

       Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

       qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');


    }


        Public Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}

        Public Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}


       Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{

       subtotalofquantity=0;

       subtotalofamount=0;
      /






         //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type 

       disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

     //Query all the list 

     list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,QuoteNumber,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,Quote.Opportunity.id, 
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];



     Opportunity opp =[select id , Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), probability, AccSegment__c from Opportunity where opportunity.Id =:q[0].opportunity.id];

    list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.id,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,    gmod__date__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,Forecast_Date__c,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id  order by gmod__Month__c asc ]; 



       //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  
        PartMap = new Map<String,Decimal>();

      //  PartMapQuantity = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter1 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter2 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter3 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter4 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount1 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount2= new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount3 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount4 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        for(gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast : opflist)
        {
            if(oppforecast .gmod__Month_Text__c=='Jan' || oppforecast .gmod__Month_Text__c=='Feb'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Mar')

                   {
                       if(Quarter1.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name ))
                             {
                                  Quarter1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                  Amount1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                  //PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c,PartMap.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                 // PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c,PartMap.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);  
                              }
                        else
                              {

                                 Quarter1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                 Amount1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                // PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                // PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                                 wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                                 w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                                 w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                                 w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                                 w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                                 w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                                 w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                                 w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                                 w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                                 w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                                 w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                                 w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                                 w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                                 w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                                 disp_list.add(w);
                            } 
                         }

                 if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Apr' ||oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='May'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='June')

                          {

                               if(Quarter2.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
                                       {
                                           Quarter2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                           Amount2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                        }
                              else
                                         {

                                            Quarter2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                            Amount2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                                            wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                                            w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                                            w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                                            w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                                            w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                                            w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                                            w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                                            w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                                            w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                                            w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                                            w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                                            w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                                            w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                                            w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                                            disp_list.add(w);

                                        }
                           }
                 if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Jul' || oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Aug'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Sept')

                        {

                              if(Quarter3.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
                                      {
                                          Quarter3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                          Amount3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                       }
                             else
                                       {

                                          Quarter3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                          Amount3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                                          wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                                          w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                                          w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                                          w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                                          w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                                          w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                                          w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                                          w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                                          w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                                          w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                                          w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                                          w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                                          w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                                          w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                                          disp_list.add(w);

                                    }
                            }
              if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Oct' || oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Nov'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Dec')
                      {
                          if(Quarter4.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
                             {
                                      Quarter4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                      Amount4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                             }
                     else
                             {

                                      Quarter4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                      Amount4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                                      wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                                      w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                                      w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                                      w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                                      w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                                      w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                                      w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                                      w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                                      w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                                      w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                                      w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                                      w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                                      w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                                      w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                                     disp_list.add(w);
                            }

                   }


        for (Quote qt :q){
             System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());



            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++){

            subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c);




                                        //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                                        wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();


                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

                 w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                 w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

                 w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

                 w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

                 w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

                 w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

                 w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

                 w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

                 w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;

                 w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;

                 w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c; 


                              //Adding everthing to the List  


                            // w.name =qt.name;

                           //   disp_list.add(w);

                              // return disp_list;  
}

}
              }       
              }
         } //End of Class
```

This Is code for the Quarter1.Similarly it follows for the other Quarters.Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the query you are firing for this.

Comment: @Animesh:The Query     list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,    gmod__Amount__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id  order by gmod__Month__c asc ];

Comment: Your code looks ok. Try including the VisualForce code that is printing out the table. You are most likely doing something wrong and printing out all elements in your loop 4 times.  If you click **edit** under your question you will be able to update it with the VisualForce code

Comment: @BarCotter:I have updated the Visual force code.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what is in the `disp_list` variable to make sure that it has the correct values in it and no duplicates?

Comment: @yes it has the correct values. i have updated complete code.